# Custom image size from flickr api?

Tags: flickr

is there a way how to get images from flickr api with custom width/height? I found only standard function `flickr.photos.getSizes`, but this functions returns only predefined sizes. Thank's

Comment: Just in case you are still looking for a good photo CDN, Google allows custom sizes through public Picasaweb feeds

Comment: You can convert any image from any domain using Sencha.io Src service - http://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/

Append the URL of the image to be resized to the end of the Sencha.io Src URL while also specifying the desired dimensions in the URL: http://src.sencha.io/32/32/http://example.com/670image.jpg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to have flickr resize the photos for you (except for the default options) Depending on the system you are building there are a couple of options:

- use one of the flickr provided sizes ... ;-)
- If you are using HTML: resize the image in the browser by setting the width and the height of the image (make sure you enable the right settings in IE for maximum viewing pleasure: http://code.flickr.com/blog/2008/11/12/on-ui-quality-the-little-things-client-side-image-resizing/)
- If you are using flash resizing the image should not be a big issue
- If you have a php or java (or any other language really) backend you can use that to scale the image.

Also: check http://www.flickr.com/groups/api and http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/yws-flickr/